# where is android target strings on LibGdX project?

Tags: android, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This maybe noob question but the answer is not easy to find on the Internet or theres no direct answer.

I am trying to use a old LibGdx project that targets android-19.
I want to target android 25 or higher. 
But I failed to find where to change those strings.
I searched on build.gradle but found nothing. So help required now.

I am attaching the whole Android/build.gradle:

```
    android {
    buildToolsVersion project.androidToolsVersion
    compileSdkVersion project.androidSDKVersion.toInteger()
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}

// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def adb = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android/com.badlogicgames.superjumper.android.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitely, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]       
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to android/build.gradle

**Update**

try that:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion project.androidToolsVersion
    compileSdkVersion project.androidSDKVersion.toInteger()
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
     }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.companie.project" // I don't know if it's really usefull in your case
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally, you have a build.gradle at the root, and then you have a build.grable in each plateform folder.
To find the `targetSdkVersion`, go to Android folder, and open the build.gradle which is inside.

Comment: I updated with the code from gradle file for android.

Comment: nothing with those added. And Target android version - string not seen yet. I'll experiment more though.

Answer (score 0):

Find `defaultConfig` inside `android` tag in `build.gradle` file of android module.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.its.mygame"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23             // This is what you want, change here
    ...
}
```

If not present there open `AndoidManifest.xml` file of your android module.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />  //change here
```

---

What if present in both place ?

Configuration of `AndroidManifest.xml` will override by `defaultConfig` configuration of build.gradle.